# SQL Count first occurrence

Tags: sql, distinct

My original database looks like that:

```
TYPE CONTRACT_ID
a    101011 
c    101012
b    101011
b    101012
a    101011-1
c    101012
```

I am trying to get data, grouped by TYPE, counting unique CONTRACT_ID, but some contracts have subcontracts, like 101011 has subcontract 101011-1. All of them have to be counted as one contract.

I have tried distinct and it works but only partially because those subcontracts still being counted as unique entrees.

```
SELECT TYPE, count(distinct CONTRACT_ID) as countocc
FROM db_address
group by TYPE
```

I expect output like that:

```
TYPE  countocc
a     1 
b     2
c     1
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using..?

Answer (score 1):

How about ignoring the subcontracts all-together?  You seem to have the parent contract when you have the subs:

```
SELECT TYPE, count(distinct CONTRACT_ID) as countocc
FROM db_address
WHERE CONTRACT_ID NOT LIKE '%-%'
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement to count only the part of `contract_id` before the `'-'` (if it exists):

```
select 
  type,
  count(distinct 
    case 
      when contract_id like '%-%' then 
        substring(contract_id, 1, instr(contract_id, '-') - 1)
      else contract_id
    end
  ) counter
from db_address
group by type
```

This covers the case (if there is such a case) that a subcontract is in the table but not the main contract.
The code works for MySql but all the functions used can be found in any rdbms.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8z2Fqkp4mMBqVY9CYaqcSY/0).
Results:

```
| type | counter |
| ---- | ------- |
| a    | 1       |
| b    | 2       |
| c    | 1       |
```

Comment: `instr()` is a product spesific function, wheras we don't know the DBMS.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I mentioned: *all the functions used can be found in any rdbms* maybe by different names. but they exist

Answer (score 0):

The logic might be extracting the part of the string upto the dash character, if exists, and then grouping by `type` column. But method differs depending on the `DBMS`.

If you're using <kbd>[`Oracle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8457dd3a269fae207de228c560850719)</kbd>, consider :

```
select type, 
       count( distinct
             case when instr(contract_id,'-') > 0 then
                  substr(contract_id,1,instr(contract_id,'-')-1)
             else
                  contract_id
             end) as countocc
  from db_address d
 group by type
```

If <kbd>[`SQL Server`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=16b3f87095e1b1e00ee4cafacb3bead2)</kbd>, then consider :

```
select type, 
       count( distinct
             case when charindex('-',contract_id) > 0 then
                  left(contract_id,charindex('-',contract_id)-1)
             else
                  contract_id
             end) as countocc
  from db_address d
 group by type;
```

If <kbd>[`MySQL`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbb6e20a1921146d909a422e1ceb20a8)</kbd>, then consider :

```
select type, 
       count(distinct substring(contract_id,1,instr(contract_id,'-')-1)) as countocc
  from db_address d
 group by type;
```

If <kbd>[`PostGRES`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c6c85042995c1bbfe922e7f15e88654a)</kbd> , then consider :

```
select type, 
       count( distinct
             case when strpos(contract_id,'-') > 0 then
                  substr(contract_id,1,strpos(contract_id,'-')-1)
             else
                  contract_id
             end) as countocc
  from db_address d
 group by type;
```